# What might be killing the output to my amp, with every modification I try to make to my audio circuit?

Tags: audio, frequency-divider

I’ve been working on an audio project connected to a unique Stylophone-type keyboard (that I designed), using a 555 timer for the main circuit. I built a really cool box with 5 little powered outlets in it and have been hoping to figure out a circuit that would go between my main board and my little amp, that would make the whole thing sound edgier. I’m shooting for a bagpipe-like sound.

I was hoping I could modify the sound or frequency from my main circuit and then do some mixing.

I’ve been playing with circuit after circuit and nothing works. Most of the time I can barely hear anything out of my little amp (built around an NMJ386B chip).

My entire schematic set for the 3 circuits on my main board and the voltage regulator/outlet circuit built into the box is below.

This morning, I tried the simplest thing I could think of—a duplication of something that is already on my main board: running the output of the first 555 circuit through a flip-flop as a frequency divider, and the output from that to my little amp. I plugged the circuit into the first power outlet in my box, to which the main board is also plugged in. I checked the 74LS74 dual flip-flop chip—as I had removed it from a board—by swapping it in and out of my main board. It works fine. I also plugged in a different power supply with a higher (1A) rating.

When I touch a contact device to my keyboard, the sound out of my amp is very, very faint. So faint it’s hard to tell if the frequency range of my keyboard has changed. But, I think not.

I’ve been playing with all kinds of circuits—octave-ups and circuits that I hoped might vary pulse width external to the 555, for instance, mostly using CMOS logic gates. As I really don’t want to deconstruct my main board—which all works, even if doesn’t sound exactly the way I’d like it to.

I read here ([How do I connect a 555 timer to a CMOS Input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101523/how-do-i-connect-a-555-timer-to-a-cmos-input)): “If you run the CMOS from the same supply voltage there should be no problem in directly connecting the 555 to a CMOS input.”

So, I thought maybe the problem was as simple as mis-matched supply voltages. That’s why I finally decided to try something that was already on my main board, that works fine there, and attach it to the same supply voltage. Something that I figured had to work a second time. But, it doesn’t. I also checked for bad wiring connections to my connecting jack and plug. No problems there.

What am I missing? What am I not getting? What is possibly killing the output to the amp?

[image: Schematic Set]

Comment: The 74LS04 max voltage is 7V. 9V will damage it.

Comment: I've got it plugged into the outlet that only puts out about 6.33V.

Comment: According tothe schmatic diagram, the voltage required is 12 V. The voltage applied to the 74LS74 is labeled X which I assume is 9V although that is not indicated. The dual flip-flop should be operated at 5 V.

Comment: What requires 12 volts? I've got 12V going into my 9V voltage regulator circuit, which then has a bunch of diodes in series with the first outlet. The dual flip-flop on my main board has survived everything I may've stupidly thrown at it, including busting a pin when I desoldered it from a board and then soldered a new pin on, as well as powering the board originally with a wall wart rated 7 volts.

Comment: The add-on circuit I tried this morning is essentially the same as my 'drones' circuit, with the exception of the attached keyboard: 555 timer circuit output at pin 3 to dual flip-flop IC to amp. I can't figure out why it would work in one place and not in another. Could it have anything to do with my on-board mixing circuit? I'm building my add-on circuits on breadboard, plugging them into the amp jack in my box, and then connecting to the amp via another jack. I've also been testing all of my add-on circuits without stepping on the foot pedal that adds in the drones circuit.

Comment: The 74LS74 is being used incorrectly so it is a problem, but likely not a problem that causes  no output. The supply voltage and input volrage should be within 4.75 and 5.25 V range. While your design likely has the supply below the absolute maximum of 7V, it is exceeding the limit of 5.5 for the input. Also unused inputs are left unconnected. That's no way to use an 74LS chip properly. Why not just run everything with 5V and use the chip properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing circuit is dropping most of the signal across the 10k resistor, output from mixer is 1k/(10k+1k) = 1/11 of the input signal. I would try increasing the size of the 1k resistor in the mixing circuit. This should increase the signal amplitude going to the amp assuming that your amp's input resistance is fairly large

Also, as a separate issue you need a resistor between pins 2&6 and pin 7 of the 555 Timer Drones circuit.

Is your amp ac coupled on its input? (that is to say does it have a capacitor in series with its input?). If not then you need to add an ac coupling capacitor (probably of the non-polarised variety) between the mixer and the amp.

Comment: I got that mixing voltage divider here:

https://hackaday.com/2015/02/04/logic-noise-sweet-sweet-oscillator-sounds/

“If you’re going to connect ... up to something valuable, you’re going to want to reduce the output down to line levels ... that means dividing down by a factor of nine-ish ... with a simple voltage divider [second schematic on page].”

His VD shows a 100K and 10K resistor. I got the values wrong by a factor of 10! Should I up the value of BOTH resistors? Or, gurus, do something completely different?

@user350400, what value would you suggest for the AC coupling cap?

Comment: @Explorer The 555 will be able to drive your values OK (enough output current capability) so they should be OK. The AC coupling capacitor value depends upon the output resistance of the mixer and the input resistance of the amp but personally I would try a ball-park value of say 10uF and increase it if necessary. Assuming the input to the amp is biased up to mid-supply - check this (assuming it's a single voltage supply amp) and the dc output level from the mixer is nearer to 0V so I would put the positive side of the electrolytic towards the amp.

Comment: @Explorer With the amp disconnected from the mixer, measure the DC level on the input to the amp and then you'll be more confident about which way around to connect the electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: For a 10k input volume control and 50Hz then use a 330nF capacitor (0.33uF). Use a plastic film capacitor (nonpolarized).

Comment: To answer @user350400: with amp disconnected and DMM probes attached to amp jack pins, and a contact device on my Stylophone-type keyboard, DMM reads 0.0V. Would this be right? But, I've decided to do some desoldering. I've decided my mixing circuit looks pretty wonky. I'm going to insert 2 identical pots (as voltage dividers to ground) and 2 identical fixed resistors. Does it matter where I put the fixed resistors? Feeding the non-grounded 'ears' or coming off the wipers? @audioguru?

Comment: @user350400, my drones circuit has seemed to work fine for quite awhile now. What's the danger of not having a resistor between pins 6 & 7? How small could it be? Will it mess up my ability to tune the frequency to ~440 Hz? Will I end up having to change my resistance values going from pin 7 to +/pin 8? (I'm trying to figure out how much desoldering I'm getting into.) Thanks!

Comment: The datasheet of your NJM386 amp is VERY blurry. It is a copy of an LM386 amp so look at its datasheet. It shows that its inputs are already at 0V ground which is why a non-polarized input capacitor is needed. I do not know how you are making a passive and volume controlled mixer circuit. Usually a mixer circuit uses an inverting opamp.